# Jquery Functions in Unordered List

Tags: jquery, click, html-lists

I have list items in an unordered list that are calling functions via jquery click events.  The problem is the li is calling its function then calling the parent ul function.  I just want the function called that I am referencing with the id.  Is it a parent-child issue?

```
<ul id="mainlist">
  <li id="item1">list1</li>
  <li id="item2">list2</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$("#mainlist").click(function {
   someFunction();
  });
$("#item1").click(function {
  someOtherFunction();
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to stop the event from propagating to its ancestors:

```
$("#item1").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  someOtherFunction();
});
```

Or, you could check the clicked element (the `event.target`) to see if it's the `<ul>` or the `<li>` by checking its `id` property:

```
$("#mainlist").click(function (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
        case 'mainlist':
          someFunction();
          break;
        case 'item1':
          someOtherFunction();
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
});
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).
- jQuery:

  - [`Event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation).

Comment: I checked the documentation and tried the return false option and this works too.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :)